# Superslides.js with fixed img position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Case:**

Our website has a superslides plugin running on top of the page, which been cut off about 100 px before the end of the page so we have a menu bar. When you scroll down, the menu bar scrolls along and fixes itself to the top, which is doing as it is supposed to. However, the image scrolls along too, which we dont want. We want the image to be fixed to the background, so it looks likes everything is scrolling over the images of the superslides.

The work on our test domain is shown as here: http://test.thewebfanatics.com/jellyweb/

**Problem:**

Since it has an image tag, i cant the position cover on it on a background image, that would be the logical approach for me, but because its a slider and javascript driven, I am forced to do a different approach.

As I am trying to add a position fixed to the slider, no matter what div I grab, it all shifts, the menu bar dissapears and only appears when i start scrolling and ending up at the position i tell it to fix on the top, the slider is staying fixed however, but the content is moved up. I also tried in the js on the calling instance to set the scrollable variable to false, but neither any luck. I think it is an issue with the positions absolute and relative, yet i cant seem to figure it out.

**code**

The code itself is quite long, but i will try to give you the relevant code

```
<div class="topwrap">

<div class= "resolutionwrap hidden-phone" id="slider">
    <div id="slides">
        <ul class="slides-container" id="home">
            <li>
                <img src="img/slides/picture4.jpg"/>
                <div class="containercaption">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <h3 class="captiontitle">
                                <?php
                                    switch ($_SESSION['language']) {
                                        case "nl":
                                            echo "The Web Fanatics Slaan een brug tussen jou en je doelgroep";
                                            break;
                                        case "en":
                                            echo "The Web Fanatics create a bridge between you and your targetgroup";
                                            break;
                                        case "pl":
                                            echo "Poolse vertaling";
                                            break;  
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://test.jellyfishwebdesign.nl/jellyweb/diensten/webdesign"><img src="img/slides/responsive-slide.jpg" width="1680" height="auto" alt=""/></a>
                <div class="containercaption">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <h3 class="captiontitle">Mobile Friendly & Responsive Design</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<!-- end slider -->

    <nav>
        (whole bunch of nav code)    
    </nav>
</div>

</div>  

<section class="content">
     (filled with content)
</section>
```

The CSS for the slider

```
#slides {
    position: relative;
}
#slides .slides-container {
    display: none;
}
#slides .scrollable {
    *zoom: 1;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 100%;
}
#slides .scrollable:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.slides-navigation {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 46%;
    width: 100%;
}
.slides-navigation a {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
.slides-navigation a.prev {
    left: 0;
}
.slides-navigation a.next {
    right: 0;
}

.slides-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.slides-pagination a {
    border: 2px solid #222;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    *vertical-align: auto;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=");
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -100%;
}
.slides-pagination a.current {
    background: #222;
}



.resolutionwrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

And as last the javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($('.resolutionwrap').length == 1) {
        var documentScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop() + 100;
        var fixedToggle = $('#slides').height();

        if (documentScrollTop > fixedToggle) {
            $('#hoofdmenu').addClass('fixed');
            $('#hoofdmenu').css("margin-top", "0px");
        } else {
            $('#hoofdmenu').removeClass('fixed');
            $('#hoofdmenu').css("margin-top", "-100px");
        }
    }
});

function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}  
var p = getUrlParameter('p');

var str = window.location.pathname;
var page = str.split("/");
x=page[2];
var l = x=page[2]; 

if (p === 'home' || p === undefined){ 
    if (l === 'home' || l === 'undefined' || l === ''){ 
        $('#slides').superslides({
            play: 5000,
            scrollable: false
        });
    } else {
         $('#hoofdmenu').addClass('fixed');
         $('.resolutionwrap').addClass('banner-place');
    }   
} else {
     $('#hoofdmenu').addClass('fixed');
     $('.resolutionwrap').addClass('banner-place');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position: fixed !important; to #slides, then add z-index: 1; to #slides too.
After that you can add z-index: 2; to the elements that have to be visible above the slider.

Comment: its a nice try, but javascript seems to overwrite it, but I think its a nice step in the right direction. I ll play with this (higher z-index, cause the js assigns higher valued z-index as well) i ll look into it further. Thanks for the direction

Comment: Can't you change to Javascript that it won't overwrite your CSS?

Comment: I can actually, i found the corresponding lines to fix that (within superslides.js), however, i still have the menu still keeps dissapearing, it wont scroll, dissapears and after it's on top it appears again. I need to figure that out, but I think i can work with this at least for now :) When i fix it, i ll accept your answer as the correct one ;) thumbs up for at least pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I can't imagine exactly what the problem could be at this moment, but you're welcome and nice website;)

Comment: Solved it. it required me to assign a negative value to the slides div (had to do with the fact the div slides is in the same container as the main menu, so it wouldn't behave the same as described in your answer), so it worked propperly. Then I had to reset the margin-top value on the menu, which now brought a new problem a long, but I think I can work my way out of this.

Comment: Thanks, and your website looks great! Can I send you a private message somewhere?

Comment: i completely missed this comment, @thommylue. I am not sure if S.O. has a messaging system. In my profile is a link to my twitter. You can try that.